# How can I 301 Redirect Shopify pages after closing online store?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, shopify

I'm moving my eCommerce store from Shopify to my domain. All pages that were previously hosted on Shopify are now hosted on the same server as my domain  (using "Buy Button" instead of "Online Store"). I would basically like to 301 redirect all Shopify pages to their new URLs.

I know that Shopify has a built-in 301 Redirect tool, but when I remove "Online Store" as a sales channel, all of these redirects stop working. Luckily I was able to add it back without a hassle.

The Shopify support rep I spoke with had no idea what a URL redirect was so I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Should I be doing this via the .htaccess on my server instead of through Shopify?

Any help would be much appreciated.

-Angela

Answer (score 0):

If you are going away from Shopify then you need to set up the redirects on the host where your DNS points.

This can be a .htaccess or in your apache config. Once you've moved there's nothing at Shopify that will help.